# Magento: Remove Dash from between sku and custom option sku

Tags: php, magento

I am looking to remove the "-" in our SKU's when a customer purchases a product that has a custom option.

For example they buy a shirt and choose custom option size 28

The SKU in the order becomes shirt-28

We need it to become instead shirt28

I think I am supposed to edit

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php
```

but cannot identify the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's on line 1037 at /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php

turn this code

```
  if ($product->getNameAutogenerate()) {
            $product->setName($configurableProduct->getName() . '-' . implode('-', $autogenerateOptions));
        }

        if ($product->getSkuAutogenerate()) {
            $product->setSku($configurableProduct->getSku() . '-' . implode('-', $autogenerateOptions));
        }
```

into this

```
  if ($product->getNameAutogenerate()) {
            $product->setName($configurableProduct->getName() . '' . implode('', $autogenerateOptions));
        }

        if ($product->getSkuAutogenerate()) {
            $product->setSku($configurableProduct->getSku() . '' . implode('', $autogenerateOptions));
        }
```

but **highly recommended not to edit core files. better do observer.**

Answer (score 0):

you have to Override this Abstract model, to do so just copy this file from

> web/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Abstract.php

to your local codepool :

> web/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Abstract.php

then remove the dash inside the getOptionSku function arround line 742:

```
public function getOptionSku($product = null, $sku=''){
        //$skuDelimiter = '-';
        $skuDelimiter = '';
        ...
}
```